# Can't execute sharepoint scripts remotely

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Let see if someone can help me. I am getting nuts with this simple script that I can execute remotely.

To put in context, I am trying to execute a sharepoint script from a server one server that I don't have Sharepoint installed. This is the script that I am trying to run:

```
$SPUser = "Sharepoint_user"
$SPPassword = "SharePoint_Password"
$Password = convertto-securestring -String $SPPassword -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentList $SPUser, $Password
$SPServer = "Sharepointserver"

 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SPServer -Credential $cred -ErrorVariable InvokeErrorMessage -Scriptblock {

         Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea continue
         Get-SPWeb -Identity 'https://sharepointsite.com'


    }#end Invoke-Command
```

And this the error that I got:

```
Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate 
permissions to access the database before trying again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb], SPCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb
If I run the same script in the Sharepoint server (off course without the invoke-command), the script works perfectly.
```

The user account that I am using is already member of the Farm and the Site Collection Group and has Admin permission in the Sharepoint server. Also, has permission to execute sharepoint scripts in the SQL server (SharePoint_Shell_Access) and is set as "sysadmin" and "dbcreator".

I also tried to execute with NEW-PSSSESSION but it doesn't work too. I got the same error.

Any idea of what I am missing to configure?

Thanks in advance for the help!

I already tried with execute with Invoke-Command and New-PsSession
Reviewed the permissions of the user account if the Sharepoint Farm Configuration
Reviewed the roles and permissions in the SQL Database
Tested to execute a helloworld powershell script remotely (without any Sharepoint cmdlet) and works properly

Comment: This looks like the famous "double hop" problem. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-7.3 for more info

Comment: Hi Bluuf.
I am not sure if this is the problem because, there are a lot of documentation in internet explainning  that this is posible to do, for example:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/06/how-to-remotely-execute-sharepoint-powershell-cmdlets.html

Also, I tried in the first hop to open a new powershell passing the again the credentials:

powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell | c:\temp\script.ps1" -Credential (get-Credential)

And didn't works too.

Comment: Hey Bluff, you know what? You were right!
I followed the procedure of this site and now it's working correctly!

https://janikvonrotz.ch/2014/04/30/sharepoint-powershell-remoting-double-hop-scenario/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a double hop issue with the Powershell.

I followed the procedure of this site and now it'sm working properly:

https://janikvonrotz.ch/2014/04/30/sharepoint-powershell-remoting-double-hop-scenario/